# Import .csv file in Weka tool

Tags: weka

I want to use Weka tool.

1. I have an .xlsx file
2. I convert it to .csv file. To open it in Weka

But when I import the .csv file this error message appears:

[image]

What can I do ?

Comment: Does this issue only occur with the 1 file. It reads as if the issue is about the CSV file not being recognized. Any way, this question is off topic, it's not about programming

Comment: It is very likely that the data in the Excel file contains commas. You can check it, and you can set the cell type as text and export it enclosed in `""` or in `''`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have uniform number of comma separated data in each line of file. If you have 4 data in one line and you have 2 data in second line exception will occur in second line or row. I also got same problem and i verified it by uploading small test file with uniform number of data item in each line.